# How to instantiate Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, factory

I get this error when I want to instantiate Factory. I need the instantiation because of a method, `make()` to render blade files.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Cannot
>   instantiate interface Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory

The source code

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

class PDFGenerator
{

    private $view;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new ViewFactory();
        $this->generatePDF();
    }

    public function generatePDF()
    {

        $html = $this->loadView('template');

    public function loadView($view, $data = array(), $mergeData = array(), $encoding = null){
        return $this->view->make($view, $data, $mergeData)->render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a misconception on how factory/interface work.
The point of interface is that you **do not** instantiate it, you only have the methods name with argument(s) in place so every classes that implement it all have unify interface.

In this case if you look at the `Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory` you'll see that there is no real processing done here only the code that say "Okay, this is what this method will do, what inputs it expected and what output will be given". You'll see that there's no mention of how to do it, the class that implement that interface is the one who suppose to know how to do it, not the interface.

---

To the solution of your problem

When you want to render view you have 2 options

1. Use the `view()` [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-view). (Preferred)
2. Use the `View::make()` method from `View` [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades)

Comment: Thank you for your enlightenment, I already solved the problem though. But your explanation helped me understand it better.